# Google Apps Script Return HTML Syntax Error

Tags: google-apps-script

Hey guys I'm very new to coding and I have encountered a Syntax error that I can't seem to figure out. I've looked online for the error and what's worse, I've managed to get the script to work earlier today before receiving the error. I am trying to take rows from a Google Sheet and pin them onto a map.

The error I receive is on line 9 where I try to return the array. Any input or suggestions would be much appreciated it! Thank you guys for trying to help. Specifically:

```
return html.evaluate().setTitle('Company Directory Map');
```

Here is the code that I have:

```
function doGet(e) {

  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DirectoryHTML');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  html.ss = parseDirectory(ss.getSheetByName('Directory Address & Name').getRange('A2:R').getValues());

  return html.evaluate().setTitle('Company Directory Map');

}

function parseDirectory(values) {
 var locations = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    locations.push({
      LocationID: values[i][1],

      LocationName: values[i][4],
      Address: values[i][6],
      AddressDetail: values[i][7],
      City: values[i][8],
      State: values[i][9],
      Zipcode: values[i][10],
      ZipcodeExtension: values[i][11],
      mapURL: getMapUrl(values[i][6,8,9,10,11]),
      Phone: values[i][12],
      Fax: values[i][13],
      EnteralPhone: values[i][14],
      EnteralFax: values[i][15],
      Type: values[i][16],
      Notes: values[i][17]

     });
    }
      return locations;
    }

function getMapUrl(city) {
  return Maps.newStaticMap().setSize(1200, 600).setCenter(41.37132419162449,-112.13662837438801).getMapUrl();
}
```

**Edit**
Below is my HTML code for reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
   <? = for(var i = 0, i < locations.length; i++) {?>
      <div>
      <img src = "<? locations[i].mapUrl ?>" />
      <h2><?= locations[i].LocationID ?></h2>
      <!-- <h4><?= locations[i].Address ?></h4> -->
      </div>
   <? } ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error you get exactly? And could you share your HTML code?

Comment: The error says exactly: SyntaxError: Syntax error. (line9, file "Directory")

Comment: You set the value of object `ss` here `html.ss = parseDirectory(..)`. But use `var locations` in the HTML code. [Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#pushing_variables_to_templates) for proper syntax. Your code should be `html.locations = parseDirectory(..)`

Comment: @JackBrown I really appreciate you spotting that error. When I go back to fixing the error and rerunning the script, I still have SyntaxError: Syntax error. (line 9, file "Directory"). When I try to debug however, the same error pops up followed immediately by "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again." I've been at it for about 5 hours now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for syntax error is you have syntax error in your HTML code, specifically this line

```
<? = for(var i = 0, i < locations.length; i++) {?>
```

1) You are using printing scriptlet, but there is no variable/output to print. Use standard scriptlet instead `<? ?>`
2) The proper syntax for the loop is `for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)`. Note the use of `;` instead on `,` in the loop.

Finally, you set the value of `ss` object in you `htmltemplate`

```
html.ss = parseDirectory(ss.getSheetByName('Directory Address & Name').getRange('A2:R').getValues());
```

However, in your HTML code, you use the object `locations` to run through the loop. Hence modify your HTML code like so

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <? var locations = ss ?>
   <?  for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {?>
      <div>
      <img src = "<?= locations[i].mapUrl ?>" />
      <h2><?= locations[i].LocationID ?></h2>
      <!-- <h4><?= locations[i].Address ?></h4> -->
      </div>
   <? } ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sir, thank you so much for your knowledge, input, and expertise on this! I've been stumped for 5 hours looking through documentations and other similar questions on Stack Overflow. Thank you again for everything!

Comment: If this answers your question, consider accepting the answer as defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)